# Ask for a vague answer to be expanded upon, or provide a more fleshed out answer?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked [How to create shared topology using PyAnsys and PyVista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69283306/how-to-create-shared-topology-using-pyansys-and-pyvista), and only received one answer. Considering the low number of PyAnsys and Ansys questions on Stack Overflow, this was certainly to be expected. Whilst this initial answer definitely put me on the right track, it was somewhat vague.

Rather than ask for it to be expanded upon, I simply upvoted it and came up with my own solution (which I then accepted as the correct answer).

However, when reviewing my question afterwards, I did only ask for an MAPDL command and *not* its implementation. Which is exactly what was provided by the initial answer.

Is it considered poor practice to take a suggestion made by a vague (but objectively correct) answer, expand upon it, and then accept your own answer?

Should I rather have added an edit to my question to provide more information regarding the solution?

The above question is very niche and will likely not be looked up by very many people, but I'm curious to learn what more experienced users  would have done.

Comment: But the edit to your question would then have invalidated the existing answer, wouldn't it?

Comment: @JeanneDark That's the thing - in my mind, a question should not address anything about an answer (which is the reason I didn't go down that route).

Comment: FWIW, I don't think the original answer was good. "Look at X" doesn't really answer the question, it only tells you how to answer it yourself. It definitely does not answer the "how to" part for me.

Comment: You referenced the initial answer and provided a detailed solution to your question. I think editing your question would have been a detour. And since it's the full answer to your question, accepting it seems fair to me.

Comment: It seems that the idea of editing the question is definitely not the way to go about it. Additionally, I was initially taking the stance of "is this action fair towards the original answerer?", but after some thought I believe the better stance is "which answer is going to help the next person more?".

Comment: On a related note:
https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.108376650.913555187.1634533803-24375648.1581944145

Comment: The title of this question and the content somehow do not correspond well to each other. You didn't really ask for the vague answer to be expanded. You expanded it (which is fine). Now you ask if you should change the question afterwards and I think there are already such discussions on meta here. This question could show more research.

Comment: Why not improve the vague answer instead?

Comment: @walen Because I'm not very bright - I've only now realized that answers can be edited by other users. However, because of the large differences between the two answers (as well as the additional meshing information that I deemed necessary), it was probably better to make a new answer. Thanks though - learned something new!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it considered poor practice to take a suggestion made by a vague (but objectively correct) answer, expand upon it, and then accept your own answer?

It's generally fine, as long as you write a real answer and not *just* a code dump of what worked for you.  Accepted self-answers aren't pinned to the top across Stack Exchange sites (even before we recently unpinned all accepted answers on SO). That means community voting can decide on the relative value of the answers, so for example if a beginner just learning a language does this and accepts their answer with code containing a bunch of clunky stuff, and the other answer was good and general, the voting may favour the more vague but general answer.  (Especially if there are any actual bugs; comments can point them out.)

In this case specifically, the earlier answer is pretty low effort, just a link to the docs for some function / command and quoting a few relevant portions of it.  That's a helpful pointer, but just barely enough to not be a link-only answer.

You don't need to worry about stepping on that answer's toes: whoever wrote it wanted to point you in the right direction, but not put in the time to actually solve the full problem you were asking about.  You did, and an **answer to that question is the right place to share the results for the benefit of future readers.**  (And yes, you can accept it if you think it's going to be more helpful to future readers than the other answer.  Or just because it's what worked for you.)

In general, your answer can cite the answer that pointed you in the right direction, as a way of giving the answerer credit.  That's a good thing.

Working examples of how to use functions / commands / whatever are not a bad thing to have on SO, so there is added value in having a worked-out answer.

---

#### Editing the question?

Probably don't do that.  The real problem you're trying to solve is implied by the overall question, so your answer is still an answer to the question, not broadening it to something else.

An edit to specifically ask for how to actually use such a command, instead of just asking for its name, would invalidate the existing answer so I wouldn't recommend that.

You can (and have) achieved the best thing for everyone (working code as an answer) without stepping on any toes by invalidating an existing answer.  I think what you did was the optimal thing.

(Huge caveat: I haven't looked in any detail at the question or your answer because it's a language and subject I don't know.  I'm just assuming the answer is useful to future readers.  If not, though, it's still 100% possible for voting to decide that, since the actions taken here haven't interfered with that.)

You also don't need a new question cluttering up SO with 2 questions linked to each other that are very close followups.

Comment: This is a very good breakdown of the situation and I'll likely be using this as a guide if a similar one comes up, thank you. As you've said, community voting will lean towards an answer over time. It may turn out that my answer is not as helpful to others as it was to me. Additionally, your point regarding the acceptance of a more generalized answer is very true - creating a new one with additional information may be considered unnecessary fluff to the next person.

Answer (score -8):

> Is it considered poor practice to take a suggestion made by a vague (but objectively correct) answer, expand upon it, and then accept your own answer?

I'd say yes, in the case where the

- "expanded" part was not part of the question and
- where you're the original question author

Is it possible, that the answer only seemed vague to you because you were new?

If you think the community will benefit from the expanded answer, I think a better way is to ask a new question, which specifically asks for the "expanded" part of the question and answer it yourself.

The linked original answer is a bit controversial. The original answer only provided quotes of the documentation with links without much explanation. While that was sufficient for OP, a little flesh on that answer still would've gone a great way.

However, In general, Whenever your question had set a specific goal and there was a answer that met the goals, you cannot edit your question to change the goal post or add a extra imaginary question in your mind and answer that imaginary question as your answer and accept it. I don't think that's ok.

Comment: So the answer definitely was quite vague. Whilst I'm relatively new to PyAnsys, I'm in no way new to Python or Ansys (not saying I'm great, just not new). The PyAnsys documentation is not easy to navigate unless you have used MAPDL commands before, and it took me a great deal of time to work everything out even with the suggestion made. This being said, I am incredibly grateful for the initial answer.

Comment: @ChaddRobertson I would agree in your specific case too. But in general, I don't think this is the way to do this.

Comment: As for the suggestion regarding an additional question: There are currently only 56 Ansys questions (many without an answer) and the PyAnsys tag does not exist from what I can tell. Waiting for a more detailed answer would likely yield no results.

Comment: This is exactly why I asked on here - I am open to as many opinions as I can possibly hear, and I appreciate you taking the time to give me your point of view.

Comment: @ChaddRobertson `Waiting for a more detailed answer would likely yield no results.` My suggestion was to ask a new question and answer it yourself. Self answer it. That way you can document your knowledge in SO without having to add "extra" information to a "yes/no" or documentation question. You also don't have to think about offending the original answerer, who pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, I misread - you stated that I should answer it myself, not wait for another answer.

Comment: Offending the original answerer was one of my biggest concerns - you are right on the money. The way I tried to deal with that was to cite the initial answer in an effort to provide the credit that was due.

Comment: I agree with linking to the original answer to provide credit. Without reading your linked question however, Whenever  your question had set a specific goal and there was a answer that met the goals, you cannot edit your question to change the goal post or answer a extra imaginary question  and add it as your answer. That's generally frowned upon.

Comment: Definitely understand why it is not the done thing, because there's no point in an answer if it no longer applies to an edited question. I have not edited my question and have no intentions of doing so. I also do not believe my answer is one that addresses an imaginary question - it simply demonstrates how to make use of the suggestion made in the initial answer (as well as some meshing insights that may be helpful to the next person).

Comment: @ChaddRobertson `as well as some meshing insights` Can we consider that as "not in the original question's scope"? Then again, Even if you just added a answer, if it was helpful, you'd get upvotes. I am not convinced that changing the accepted answer immediately after posting is ok.

Comment: It is actually very closely related and therefore deemed to be a necessary inclusion - my initial question made use of PyVista to generate polydata for the two volumes, the second method does not. I cannot answer a question using a completely new method without justifying it. I'm also a little confused about what you are saying - I have not changed the accepted answer at all. I waited 25 days without accepting an answer, and mine has been the first and only accepted answer.